# find single quote with in double quote string and replace

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a json file that contains data like below. I want to replace single quote(O'Connor) with empty space in a double quote string(line 2). Can anyone help me how I achieve this using python? I am a beginner trying to understand.

test.json

```
{'Location': 'near Roe Hwy (3); Forrestfield; in Perth;', 'Name': "Sam", 'Salary': 1000, 'deptno': 10, 'dname':'sales'}

{'Location': **"near 133 Garling St; O'Connor; in Perth;",** 'Name': "Jam", 'Salary': 3000, 'deptno': 40, 'dname':'sales'}
```

the output should be like

```
{'Location': 'near Roe Hwy (3); Forrestfield; in Perth;', 'Name': "Sam", 'Salary': 1000, 'deptno': 10, 'dname':'sales'}

{'Location': **"near 133 Garling St; OConnor; in Perth;"**, 'Name': "Jam", 'Salary': 3000, 'deptno': 40, 'dname':'sales'}
```

Comment: The easy way would be to do this in a text editor.  Why do you want Python for this?

Comment: @TimRoberts I get this data everyday from an api and this json needs to be processed into sql table

Comment: Then whatever code is creating the SQL should do the RIGHT thing and properly quote those single quotes.  What is doing the import?

Comment: @TimRoberts Python script reads the data from API and creates json file.  data from json file will be picked up by google dataflow job and writes to sql server. The problem is when dataflow reads data the O'connor line, it fails saying invalid json. if i remove the quote, it is successful. Hence, i need help for replacing quote in that double quote string.

Comment: How are you creating json file? You should use json package to parse the dictionary you receive and then create file with it

Comment: @RaghavJoshi correct

Comment: That worked or there is still issue

Comment: @RaghavJoshi I was able to read data succesfully using python script but I need to eliminate single quote from the data in order to load to table, thats where I am having the issue.

Comment: I just asked that question because parsed json data uses double quote for both keys and values and you have keys in single quote in example

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
text = "\"near 133 Garling St; O'Connor; in Perth;\""
start = text.find("\"")
end = text[start+1:].find("\"")
text[start+1:end].replace('\'','')
```

In the example the text variable is a part of your json response parsed as a string